# Passport control: what airport is this?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, airports, esta, identify-this

I'd like to know what airport this is.

[image]
In the image there seem to be **three** lines (besides the two clearly visible ones, the far left one says it's for US citizens, with some other text, and for Canadians)

What's the difference between the US/Canadian and Perm. Resident/returning ESTA/B visa lines (since I assume both lead to the APC kiosks)?

Comment: A reverse Google Image Search says the image comes from [this Japanese blog post][1]. Google Translate [is quite unclear](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://newyorknewyork.blog.jp/archives/1092779.html&prev=search) though as it seems to mention a connection in Los Angeles, either on this trip or a previous trip. However, I think we can nail it down to either the TBIT terminal at LAX, one of the JFK terminals, or EWR.

Comment: Not LAX TBIT, because I was there in January and it Looks very different (no directional signs until you're in the actual hall). JFK possibly - the image gives me a déjà vu Feeling from June 2015, when I was at JFK T4, but the signage was slightly different (there were only two categories: US/Canada/Perm. Resident/Returning ESTA vs. visa-holders/first-time ESTA)

Comment: @Crazydre they have been expanding the categories of people eligible to use the kiosks, so different signage after 12 or 13 months wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @ZachLipton The blog post you point to, talks about this being in LAX with no similar scheme in place for New York.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder I think the blog post talks about it being in New York (because that's where it is), but is saying that the author of the post previously visited Los Angeles and used a kiosk there and that's why he/she was able to use the returning ESTA line in New York.

Comment: @ZachLipton  ニューヨークも入国カードを書かずに入国できるようになりました！You can now enter through New York without having to write and Entry Card.
最近ロサンゼルスを経由してニューヨークに入国していたので、あまり気にしていませんでしたが…。 Lately I have been entering the country through LAX on my way to New York so I haven't really taken much notice.
ロサンゼルスは何年も前からkiosk導入されていましたから。 They had a Kiosk set up in LAX for a few years now. Sorry my bad. There didn't USED to be a scheme like this in New York.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I searched for the screens showing wait times and found [this article](http://blipsystems.com/jfk-displays-actual-wait-times-using-sensors-that-monitor-mobile-phones/) with the screens in at JFK T4. Also an image of the same corridor:

http://77.66.117.45/~blipsyst//wp-content/uploads/2015/09/IMG_3568-300x300.jpg

Permanent resident, returning ESTA and B1/B2 holders can use the kiosks.
All other visa holders and first time ESTA visitors cannot.

I believe there might be separate APC queues for US/Canadian citizens and visitors. That could be the left most sign.

Comment: I just used the kiosk at JFK T4 a couple of weeks ago. Can confirm that they had at least very similar signs and three lines to different end points.

Comment: Great example of terrible signage. "Returning ESTA" means returning on an ESTA you've used before, or returning when you've ever used an ESTA before? In this situation I have a high change of using the wrong queue and getting unfairly scolded by the rude and denigrating USA border officials.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm pretty certain it means: "Arriving on ESTA and having been fingerprinted at the border in the last few years (even if never on ESTA)".

Comment: Using the non-APC line ("First time ESTA") is always fine.

Comment: @neo: Good to know. Signs should be clearer.

Comment: @neo I used the returning ESTA line when I was a first-time ESTA (because the Manual Queue was extreme). Simply got an X-marked receipt due to the lack of biometrics, but the X line was much shorter, so I went there, answered the questions, got the Fingerprints and photo taken and then stamped in

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Returning ESTA, at most airports, means you entered as an ESTA passenger on your current *passport*. Nowhere does it have to be on the same ESTA

Comment: @Crazydre Although it works I don't think you are *supposed* to do that.

Comment: @neo Right, it's a matter of policy at each Airport (MIA and YYZ for example allow all ESTA users, returning or not, to use APC)

Comment: The above makes me never want to travel. Never.

Comment: @Tim How so?...

Comment: "kiosk" at "JFK T4" "Returning ESTA" "fingerprinted" "non-APC" "Manual Queue" "X-marked receipt" :-P

Comment: @progo What was the difference between the US/Canadian and Perm. Resident/Returning ESTA/B visa Queues? Did they lead to a different set of kiosks?

Comment: @Crazydre: as a matter of fact, I think there was just one set of kiosks. It was confusing -- luckily the lines were empty so I could take my time to figure out my place